# Adding known objects to collision environment problem

Tags: ros, collision, environment

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I'm following the instructions at [Adding Known objects to collision environment](http://www.ros.org/wiki/motion_planning_environment/Tutorials/Adding%20known%20objects%20to%20the%20collision%20environment), but I couldn't find the bellow 2 launch files:

**Start up the environment server**

roslaunch pr2_arm_navigation_actions environment_server_right_arm.launch

**Launch the display for known model markers** (This node lets us visualize known model markers):

roslaunch planning_environment display_planner_collision_model.launch

So after I rosrun the add_cylinder in pr2_arm_navigation_tutorial, nothing will show up on rviz. Does anybody have an idea on where I can find the launch files??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30399/adding-known-objects-to-collision-environment-problem/) by [Paul Yang](https://answers.ros.org/users/1948/paul-yang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Paul,

I've just been wondering the same thing. Are you using ROS electric? It looks like that could be a diamondback tutorial. This looks like the electric equivalent:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials/Planning%20Scene/Adding%20Virtual%20Objects%20to%20the%20Planning%20Scene

Hope that helps!

James

---

Originally posted by [jwrobbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1711/jwrobbo/) with karma: 258 on 2012-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0